# Client Jersey and RESTful put with list of object

Tags: rest, arraylist, jersey, cxf, put

In my application I'm using the library jersey and Apache CXF for the implementation of the REST calls . In particular, I have created my DTO, a service and a dao to insert a record into a database through the put method.

The code below is working, but my problem is when certain to pass a list of DTO that the client reports an error:

```
/* Client Rest */
WebResource service = clientJersey.get().resource(this.baseURI);        
GaraDTO garaDTO = new GaraDTO();
garaDTO.setVersion("0");
..........................
ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("gare").accept(this.mediaType).put(ClientResponse.class, garaDTO);

/* DTO */
@XmlRootElement(name = "gara")
public class GaraDTO {

private Integer version;
. . . . . . . . . . . .
public GaraDTO(){
}

@XmlElement
public Integer getVersion() {
return version;
}
public void setVersion(Integer version) {
this.version = version;
}
. . . . . . . . . . . .
}


/* Service */
@Override
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public void putInsert(GaraDTO garaDto){
....................
//insert DB
....................
}
```

If, after having created an ArrayList of DTO, step this list to the client I get an error.

```
List<GaraDTO> listGaraDTO = new ArrayList();
listGaraDTO.add(garaDTO1);
listGaraDTO.add(garaDTO2);
.............................. 
ClientResponse response = service.path("rest").path("gare").accept(this.mediaType).put(ClientResponse.class, listGaraDTO);
```

How can I pass a list of DTO?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

If you want your API to accept a List, you need to make it actually accept a List, and not a single GaraDTO.

Answer (score -1):

// Client

```
package com.project.rest.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Client {

    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String lang;

    public Client() {
    }

    public Client(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public Client(Long id, String email, String lang) {
    this.id = id;
    this.email = email;
    this.lang = lang;
    }

    public Long getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
    return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
    }

    public String getLang() {
    return lang;
    }

    public void setLang(String lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Client [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + ", lang=" + lang + "]";
    }

}
```

//ClientService

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import com.project.rest.model.Client;

@Path("/client")
public class ClientService {

    @POST
    @Path("/sendList")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response consumeJSONList(List<Client> clientList) {

        String output = "consumeJSONList Client : " + clientList.toString() + "\n\n";

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

//JerseyClient

```
package com.project.rest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.project.rest.model.Client;
import com.project.rest.model.Device;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;

public class JerseyClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {

    List<Client> clientList = new ArrayList<Client>();
    clientList.add(new Client(1L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));
    clientList.add(new Client(2L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));
    clientList.add(new Client(3L, "pruebas@pruebas.com", "es"));

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();

    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client c = com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(clientConfig);

    WebResource webResource = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/project_rest/rest/client/sendList");

    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json").type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, clientList);

    if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed sendClientList: HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
    }

    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println("sendClientList... Server response .... \n");
    System.out.println(output);

} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

}
}
}
```

//POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.10-b01</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
  <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
  <version>0.99</version>
</dependency>
```